# Is there any .NET API using rsync?

Tags: c#, rsync

I need to have a file synchronizing feature in my .NET application. Can I make use of rsync? Is there any API available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the source code that comes with [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp), which is a "'Windows Friendly' wrapper" to the original RSync.
The source is written in c++, so it's not exactly .Net, but you can write managed C++ wrappers and use them.
It's not a direct solution, I know, but it may be somewhat helpful. (in other words, HTH)

Answer (score 19):

There is a C# implementation of RSync on github with some recent commits:

http://github.com/MatthewSteeples/rsync.net

Comment: This is kinda the same: https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Octodiff

Answer (score 4):

DeltaCopy is just a wrapper around the rsync executable.  However, librsync itself can be built on Windows as well as UNIX and GNU/Linux (see [their README](http://librsync.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/*checkout*/librsync/librsync/README?revision=1.17) and this [EE thread](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Editors_IDEs/C_CPP_CS/Q_22907606.html#a20134348)).  Thus, that's another option to consider.  You would still need some kind of unmanaged-managed interop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for some simple automation you could just write a tiny wrapper that invokes RSync via [System.Diagnostic.Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436685/issuing-command-line-statements-with-c)

I did read somewhere that someone circa 2006 created an rsync port in C#, but to be honest with you I would not consider using it cause its far from popular and impossible to find.