# sync local files with server files

Tags: c#, java, .net, vb.net

**Scenario:** I want to develop an application.The application should be able to connect to my remote server and download data to the local disk , while downloading it should check for new files and only download the new ones simultaneously creating the required(new) folders.

**Problem:** I have no idea how to compare the files in the server with the ones in the local disk.How to download only the new files from the server to the local disk?

**What am thinking?:** I want to sync the files in the local machine with the ones in the server. I am planning to use rsync for syncing but i have no idea how to use it with ASP.NET.

Kindly let me know if my approach is wrong or is there any other better way to accomplish this.

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999751/is-there-any-net-api-using-rsync? That answer recommends DeltaCopy.  RSync is also a command line app, so you could shell out to that using System.Diagnostics.Process.

Answer (score 0):

First you can compare the file names, then the file size and when all matches, you can compare the hashes of the files.

Comment: What if some new files are added to the server??

Comment: Easiest way is to implement a `pattern in filenames` stored in webserver and you can process request results from server to that of a convenient comparison. (append time/date from request) - (send last time/date to server and get a list of new files)

Answer (score 0):

I call this kind of a problem a "data mastering" problem. I synchronize our databases with a Fortune 100 company throughout the week and have handled a number of business process issues.

The first rule of handling production data is not to do your users' data entry. They must be responsible for putting any business process into motion which touches production. They must understand the process and have access to logs showing what data was changed, otherwise they cannot handle issues. If you're doing this for them, then you are assuming these responsibilities. They will expect you to fix everything when problems happen, which you cannot feasibly do because IT cannot interpret business data or its relevance. For example, I handle delivery records but had to be taught that a duplicate key indicated a carrier change.

I inherited several mismanaged scenarios where IT simply dumped "newer" data into production without any further concern. Sometimes I get junk data, where I have to manually exclude incoming records from the mastering process because they have invalid negative quantities. Some of my on-hand records are more complete than incoming data, and so I have to skip synchronizing specific columns. When one application's import process simply failed, I had to put an end to complaints by creating a working update script. These are issues you need to think ahead about, because they will encourage you to organize control of each step of the synchronization process.

Synchronization steps:

1. Log what is there before you update
2. Download and compare local vs remote copies for differences; you cannot compare the two without a) having them both in the same physical location or b) controlling the other system
3. Log what you're updating with, and timestamp when you're updating it
4. Save and close the logs
5. Only when 1-4 are done should you post an update to production

Now as far as organizing a "mastering" process goes, which is what I call comparing the data and producing the lists of what's different, I have more experience to share. For one application, I had to restructure (decentralize) tables and reports before I could reliably compare both sources. This implies a need to understand the business data and know it is in proper form. You don't say if you're comparing PDFs, spreadsheets or images. For data, you must write a separate mastering process for each table (or worksheet), because the mastering process's comparison step may be specially shaped by business needs. Do not write one process which masters everything. Make each process controllable.

Not all information is compared the same way when imported. We get in PO and delivery data and therefore compare tens of thousands of records to determine which data points have changed, but some invoice information is simply imported without any future checks or synchronization. Business needs can even override updates and keep stale data on your end.

Each mastering process's comparer module can then be customized as needed. You'll want specific APIs when comparing file types like PDFs and spreadsheets. I use EPPlus for workbooks. Anything you cannot open has to be binary compared, of course.

A mastering process should not clean or transform the data, especially financial data. Those steps need to occur prior to mastering so that these issues are caught before mastering is begun.

My tools organize the data in 3 tabs -- Creates, Updates and Deletes -- each with DataGridViews showing the relevant records. Then I can log, review and commit changes or hand the responsibility to someone willing.

Mastering process steps:

1. (Clean / transform data externally)
2. Load data sources
3. Compare external to local data
4. Hydrate datasets indicating Creates, Updates and Deletes