# RSync client in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, rsync

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any .NET API using rsync?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999751/is-there-any-net-api-using-rsync)

For one project, I need to find a RSync library to make some interaction with a linux server with rsync.

I already googled a lot, but I didn't found anything that matches:

https://github.com/kolosy/rsync.net
-->Seems to be unmaintened, undocumented

http://www.kolosy.com/wordpress/?p=8
--> Dead website

Even it's a commercial library, it's not a big deal.

Comment: Have you tried Rsync.net? If there is nothing wrong with it it doesn't need maintenance.

Comment: But it does need documentation. Everything is just put in a project, can't find how to use it in a c# program to ask to do a sync

Comment: To paraphrase the Supreme Court of the United States of America: Source code is a language designed to be readable by both computers and humans. So read the code, and you will find out how to use it.

Comment: Sure... Go read the whole c# source code to know how to use it...

Comment: Beggars can't be choosers, as my mum would say.